# ASP.NET Core file upload form binding problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to bind my view's form to upload method of controller, using tons of tutorials, for example:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.3.php
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-download-files-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

So, as I understand, if I create a controller and view, all should work.
The controller:

(async is disabled here, but in both cases result is the same)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace ExcelParser.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if (httpClient.BaseAddress == null)
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51313");
            }
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync("api/file").Result;
            ViewBag.Templates = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>().Result;

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult AddFile()
        {
            return View();
        }

        /*[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("======UPLOAD======");
            Console.WriteLine(file.FileName);
            string msg = "i go there";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }*/

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("======UPLOAD======");
            Console.WriteLine(file.FileName);
            string msg = "i go there";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

The view AddFile.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddFile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="UploadFile" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I place breakpoint in controller's `string msg = "i go there";` and go to webpage http://myhost:port/addfile. So, the view AddFile is rendered, but when I select a file and push the submit button, nothing happens. So, the problem that my controller doesn't receive a call for UploadFile action. I tried many examples and tutorials, and the result is the same - binding doesn't work.
I use ASP.NET Core 2.2

---

Checked html code in browser (Chrome 72 for Win). I expected  element attributes will be transformed by Razor. The code from browser:

```
<html><head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>AddFile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>


</body></html>
```

So, it seems Razor doesn't work, and the async method UploadFile is not fired.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("======UPLOAD======");
            Console.WriteLine(file.FileName);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("======ASYNC======");
            });
            string msg = "i go there";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

So, maybe I lost some references? This is my .cspjoj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>bf953a4d-5fe0-4538-aeb5-27f9b4437de6</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="4.5.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\Upload\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\Templates\test.xlsx" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

When I push submit button, a watch REST queries in the Network (Dev Tools) tab, it runs.... addfile POST query with URL https://localhost:44351/home/addfile. But why it happens, I can't found.

UPD0. Added and tried [HttpPost] method attribute. No result

UPD1. Added html from browser and references from csproj file.

Comment: It sounds like your tag-helpers might not be running. Check in the browser's developer tools to see whether those `asp-controller` and `asp-action` attributes have been transformed into a valid `action` attribute.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks for idea. Can you show me a valid action attribute example?

Comment: It would just be something like `/Home/UploadFile`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin It seems that tag transform doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Laser42,I made a test example based on your code , and it worked well . Did you use the browser's developer tools(press F12) to check if the request-url is like `https://localhost:44393/Home/UploadFile` in Network . [Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArmCwaND8ivicmtp1uYWCCFrKxA) is my test project , you could try . If  you still have problems , could you share the link of your project ?

Comment: @XueliChen I can't post entire project, sorry. But can you check my references list. Maybe, I lost smth? The problem is clear: my request URL is not `https://localhost:44351/Home/UploadFile`, but  `https://localhost:44351/home/addfile`. But what is the reason, I wonder

Comment: @KirkLarkin Finally, I found a solution. You was right that tag helpers don't work. I added `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` into the top of my cshtml, and helpers begin work! I ask you to write an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify which HTTP verbs are valid for an action, MVC will only match it for GET requests. Since you are making a POST request in your form, it cannot find a matching action (it is looking for `POST Home/UploadFile` but only finding `GET Home/UploadFile`).

Adding the `HttpPost` attribute to your action will fix it.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
     ...
}
```

A little side note: I would recommend that you use [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) instead of creating the `HttpClient` yourself. It is more efficient and also a lot cleaner than having the client configuration code in your action.

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but I also tried to add  [HttpPost] attribute, checked both async and sync calls - still no result. Maybe, when I have working app, I'll consider to use HttpClientFactory. But now i need this simple app to work only.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to my previous answer:

The `asp-action` attribute of your `form` element is referencing the `UploadFileAsync` method, which does not exist in your controller, since it is actually called `UploadFile` (without async). Fixing this should get you one step further.

Comment: I uncommented async method (see updated question), add some 2s task - still no result.

Comment: I suggested to correct the action name in your **cshtml file**, by removing the `Async` suffix from it. The action you are referencing cannot be found, because it does not exist. Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with the method actually being asynchronous or synchronous.

Comment: Thanks. This was also the problem, but not the main))